# Fazer truncate em todas as tabelas de um banco no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Há como usar o `TRUNCATE` para limpar todas as tabelas do banco?

```
TRUNCATE tabela;
```

Esse comando limpa uma a uma.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dá para obter o resultado, nas não diretamente.

Solução retirada [dessa resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8912749/221800):

```
mysql -Nse 'show tables' DATABASE_NAME | while read table; do mysql -e "truncate table $table" DATABASE_NAME; done
```

Ou através de [comando SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17738975/221800):

```
SELECT Concat('TRUNCATE TABLE ', table_schema, '.', table_name, ';') 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_schema in ('seuDB'); //pode listar vários DBs
```

Dá para fazer vários filtros:

```
SELECT Concat('TRUNCATE TABLE ', table_schema, '.', table_name, ';') 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_schema in ('seuDB') AND table_name NOT IN ('tabela1', 'tabela2', ...);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/DML/TruncateAll.sql).